# google prediction api "hello prediction" tutorial

Tags: r, prediction

I have run through the Google Prediction API tutorials and documentation for "hello prediction - https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world

However when training the model in the developer console my request fails with the following output:

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.6/projects/959568262740/trainedmodels?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "id": "language_id",
 "storageDataLocation": "http://storage.googleapis.com/2341234/language_id.txt"
}
```

Response:

```
400 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Training data file is empty.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Training data file is empty."
 }
}
```

I've implemented Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0: - is there anything else that I should be doing, or that may have changed between Google PRediction API v 1.6 and the tutorial. Any link to any additional tutorial or article on the subject would also be extremely valuable so can debug myself!

Answer (score 0):

Your storageDataLocation is not correct.

When you go to the Overview tab in Google Developers Console, you'll find your Project ID: xxxxx (example) and the bucket you've stored in is called yyyy (example).

Then replace the "storageDataLocation:" "xxxxx/yyyy". Should solve this problem. You need the relative path to Google Storage, and not the absolute web path.